# How can I improve the verbose code when I use enum in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The are many items in a enum class , I found there ae many  verbose code in the function `fun getLevel`.

How can I improve it?

**Code A**

```
enum class ELevel(private val labelId: Int, val alarmed: Boolean){

   Normal(R.string.Normal,false),
   Leaves(R.string.Leaves,false),
   Whispering(R.string.Whispering,false),
   Quiet(R.string.Quiet,false),
   Refrigerator(R.string.Refrigerator,false),
   Electric(R.string.Electric,false),
   Washing(R.string.Washing,true),
   Alarm(R.string.Alarm,true),
   Subway(R.string.Subway ,true),
   Factory(R.string.Factory,true),
   Car(R.string.Car,true),
   Ambulance(R.string.Ambulance,true);

   fun getLabel(mContext: Context) =  mContext.getString(labelId)

   companion object {
        fun getLevel(soundValue: Double): ELevel {
            var temp = Normal
            val i = soundValue.toInt()

            if (i in 1..10) {
                temp = Normal
            }

            if (i in 11..20) {
                temp =  Leaves
            }

            ...

            if (i in 101..110) {
                temp = Car
            }

            if (i in 111..120) {
                temp =  Ambulance
            }


            return temp
        }
   }
```

Comment: You could make the value range a property of the enum constants, then just loop over the constants until you find the one whose range contains `i`.

Comment: I want to point out using the "m" prefix for variables is called Hungarian notation and the  "m" stands for "member variable", so it is inappropriate and deliberately confusing if you use it for a function parameter name. The vast majority of programmers do not use Hungarian notation in modern programming languages because it makes code harder to read and the benefits are minimal because of IDE color-coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way that you have associates a `labelId` and `alarmed` flag with each of the enum constants, you can add an additional `maxSoundLevel` property:

```
enum class ELevel(
    private val labelId: Int,
    val alarmed: Boolean,
    val maxSoundLevel: Int,
){

    Normal(R.string.Normal,false, 10),
    Leaves(R.string.Leaves,false, 20),
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
companion object {
    fun getLevel(soundValue: Double): ELevel =
        // assuming the max sound levels are in ascending order
        values().firstOrNull { soundValue.toInt() <= it.maxSoundLevel }
            // if there is no match, throw exception. You can also just return the nullable ELevel
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown sound")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create an abstract val range and define it for each enum. After that you could simply check and get the first enum that have your soundValue in his range.

```
enum class ELevel(private val labelId: Int, val alarmed: Boolean) {

    Normal(R.string.Normal, false) {
        override val range: IntRange = 1..10
    },
    Leaves(R.string.Leaves, false) {
        override val range: IntRange = 11..20
    },
    Whispering(R.string.Whispering, false) {
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Quiet(R.string.Quiet, false) {
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Refrigerator(R.string.Refrigerator, false) {
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Electric(R.string.Electric, false){
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Washing(R.string.Washing, true){
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Alarm(R.string.Alarm, true){
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Subway(R.string.Subway, true){
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Factory(R.string.Factory, true){
        override val range: IntRange = ...
    },
    Car(R.string.Car, true) {
        override val range: IntRange = 101..110
    },
    Ambulance(R.string.Ambulance, true) {
        override val range: IntRange = 111..120
    };

    fun getLabel(mContext: Context) = mContext.getString(labelId)

    abstract val range: IntRange

    companion object {
        fun getLevel(soundValue: Double): ELevel =
            values().first { it.range.contains(soundValue.toInt()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just make `range` a constructor parameter so you don't have to keep putting `override val range: IntRange =`.

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs of the Strings are exact matches for the enum value names, you can also use identifier look-up to shorten your code a little bit more.

```
enum class ELevel(
    val alarmed: Boolean,
    private val maxSoundLevel: Int,
){

    Normal(false, 10),
    Leaves(false, 20),
    //...
    ;

    private var labelId = 0

    fun getLabel(context: Context){
        if (labelId == 0) {
            labelId = context.resources.getIdentifier(name, "id", context.packageName)
        }
        return context.getString(labelId)
    }
}
```